# How to update MySQL(MyISAM) table in parallel?

Tags: mysql, bash, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a parallel bash script with several threads. Each thread checks if record is exists then update value otherwise insert new row.
Should I care about  thread concurrency?
Should I lock unlock tables or mysql takes care about it?

my update goes over the command line:

```
#get.sh script...
# set status Downloading
mysql -uroot -pmypass -ss -e "use filestatus; call changeStatus(\"$1/$2\", 1)" 
rsync  -ar  rsync://user@server/$2/ $1/$2/
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; 
then 
# set status OK
mysql -uroot -pmypass -ss -e "use filestatus; call changeStatus(\"$1/$2\", 0)" 
else
# set status ERROR
mysql -uroot -pmypass -ss -e "use filestatus; call changeStatus(\"$1/$2\", 2)" 
fi
```

I call several **get.sh** with different parameters.

Thank you beforehand
 Arman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement locking, but that's going to defeat the purpose of having multiple threads. MyISAM only supports table level locking, so only 1 thread will be able to modify the table at a time.

If you can, put a unique index or primary key on a field(s). The do an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...  MySql will then make sure the action is atomic.

What I usually do with multi-threading/processing, is have the first thread/process get a "list" of all the jobs that need to be perform, then create a thread/fork to handle each job or batch of jobs. The parent thread/process will assure the children aren't trying to do the same thing. I'm not sure if this will work in your case.

Comment: thank you, I am managing to write/update unique record per thread eg: thread 1 manages only files starting with 1???,thread 2 files 2???, only what I wondered is if every thread writes to same table is it not dangerous?

Comment: No, the database handles any contention issues. That's what databases do. Any insert, update or delete automatically performs any needed locking.